# How to add NER tags to features

Tags: nlp, feature-extraction, named-entity-recognition

I have a set of training sentences for which I computed some float features. In each sentence, **two** entities are identified. They are either of type 'PERSON', 'ORGANIZATION', 'LOCATION', or 'OTHER'. I would like to add these types to my feature matrix (which stores float variables).

My question is: is there a recommended way to add these entity types ?

I could think of two ways for now:

- either adding TWO columns, one for each **entity**, that will be filled with entity types ids (e.g 0 to 3 or 1 to 4)
- adding EIGHT columns, one for each **entity type** and each **entity**, and filling them with 0's and 1's

Best!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use something that can easily be [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) and which is in the same range as the rest of your data.

So if all your float values are between -1 and 1, i would keep the values from your ["Named Entity Recognition"](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) in the same range.

So depending on what you prefer or what gives you the best result you could either assign 4 values in the same range as the rest of your floats or use a binary result with more columns.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the second suggestion (adding EIGHT columns, one for each entity type and each entity, and filling them with 0's and 1's) worked fine!